# About Exceptions, overriding the standard exception methods

Tags: c++, class, oop, exception

I am trying to overriding exception method, `std::exception::what()`, to make customized exception message.

The compiler says, "Exception specification of overriding function is more lax than base version", about this section:

```
class diffSizeExp : public std::exception
{
public:
    const char* what() const override {

    }
};
```

When switching the 'override' with 'noexcept' like this:

```
    class diffSizeExp : public std::exception
{
public:
    const char* what() const noexcept {

    }
};
```

It is working. However, I could not understand the different between those too, because I do want to overriding the standard method. From my knowledge, 'noexcept' means - don't throw exception, not overriding a method.

It would be appreciate if you could explain me in manners of Code efficiency and correctness. Is it the right way to handle this problem? Why does overriding not possible?

Thanks.

Comment: The exception specification like `noexcept` is part of the function signature and, when overriding virtual functions, the requirement is - generally speaking - to match signature.   The inherited `what()` specifies `noexcept`, so is not allowed to throw exceptions.  Your override specifies that it is permitted to throw exceptions. In other words, you are being more permissive - or lax according to your compiler - in your derived class than in the base class.

Comment: Hint for the future: only try _one_ thing at a time. You tried two things: removing `override`, and adding `noexcept`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need

```
class diffSizeExp : public std::exception
{
public:
    const char* what() const noexcept override {

    }
};
```

or

```
class diffSizeExp : public std::exception
{
public:
    const char* what() const noexcept {

    }
};
```

In simple terms, `const` and `noexcept` are function qualifiers. If you change those, you are not overriding a function, you're creating an overload (`void foo()` and `void foo() const` are as different as `void foo()` and `void foo(int)`).

However, `override` is not function qualifier. It's just a helper keyword, to make compiler throw an error when you are not actually overriding a virtual function. It's optional, and it's simply to help you spot potential mistakes (it's strongly recommended to use it for every virtual function tho).

Comment: Thank you for the great explanation. :)

Answer (score 2):

The `override` specifier is optional. You will still be overriding the parent function. The `noexcept` however specifies that the function does not throw anything. If you omit this, which is present on the parent function, the compiler will complain because you are then specifying that your overriding function may throw exceptions.

Comment: thank you sir! sorry, i cannot feedback yet because my reputation is too low still.